# Displaying price in Ethereum based on dollar exchange rate

Tags: ethereum

Worldcoinindex publishes its exchange rates here: https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice/json?key=eEtjflfzZRH1fFdM1xVLykSH1j5khk

If an item is $300 USD, how would I do the following?
1) extract the ETH/USD exchange rate from the array at this URL
2) Define the price, then divide by the exchange rate
3) Display the ETH price in an HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not actually related to Ethereum, it's more of a general web development question. Also, we don't know what platform is your website built on or which programming languages you use. That being said, here's a fully functioning node.js example that you can try out locally that updates the price on the page after clicking a button. You should then be able to adapt it to your specific language.

First, you'll need to install node.js from nodejs.org, create a new folder and create two files in this folder, app.js and index.html.

app.js file:

```js
//install these two by running 'npm install request' and 'npm install express'
//from the command line in the newly created folder
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');

//starting a local web server you can access at http://localhost:8547/
//and view the actual web page
var app = express(); 
app.listen(8547);

//make sure you get another apiKey if you go over the 70 requests/hour limit
const apiUrl = 'https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice/json?key='
const apiKey = 'eEtjflfzZRH1fFdM1xVLykSH1j5khk';

//eth-usd pair is at the index 344 in the response JSON file
const ethIndexInJson = '344';

const requestUrl = apiUrl + apiKey;

//this is the response we'll send when user clicks the update price button
app.get('/eth-price', (req, res) => {
      request.get(requestUrl, (error, response, body) => {
      //here's the JSON response from worldcoinindex
      var json = JSON.parse(body);

      //and here's the actual price extracted
      priceOfEthInUsd = json.Markets[ethIndexInJson].Price_usd;

      //now we send back the price converted to a string 
      res.send(priceOfEthInUsd.toString());
    })            
})

//setting index.html as the home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {        
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

This is your index.html file that will be updated with the new ETH price. It contains a paragraph with the id of 'eth-price', a button and a script that will request the new price from the app.js file. You shouldn't care too much about the whole XMLHttp mumbo-jumbo now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="eth-price">here's where the price will go</p>

    <button onclick="updatePrice()">Update price</button>

    <script>
    function updatePrice() {

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          //this is where we update the HTML with our new price contained
          //in the response
          var newPrice = this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("eth-price").innerHTML = newPrice;
        }
      };

      //eth-price is the path we defined in the app.js file in the get method
      xhttp.open("GET", "eth-price", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Open up your browser, head to http://localhost:8547 and try it out.